# Azure Storage Explorer crashes

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am importing data in a CSV to `Azure Table Storage` using the **Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer** application. It's pretty wide with 100+ columns.

When I import a sample of 10 rows it works fine. When I try to load the complete data set (60K rows), Azure Storage Explorer crashes.

I am about to explore other tools (PowerShell, console app, etc.). Before I do I was wondering if there is some restriction I am missing or overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am importing data in a CSV to Azure Table Storage using the Azure Storage Explorer application

I also repro the issue with [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/).
As I know that  Azure Storage Explorer is not actively maintained for long time.

It works correctly for me with [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/). Please have a try to use  Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, it may work correctly if the CSV file is not over limitation. More info about Azure storage table limitation please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits).

> Max size of a table entity **1M**
>
> Max number of properties in a table entity  252
>
> Max size of a single  table   500T

The following is my test result.

[image]

**Update1:**

If there is an entity that size is larger that **1M**, then Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer tool also crashed for me. Please have a try to check whether there is a entity that size is large that 1M. If it is that case, the CSV file may not be import to the Azure storage table as table is limited that table entity size less than 1M.

[image]

We aslo can send our feedback to tool team, if we meet any problem.

[image]

Comment: Corrected the name of the application. I am using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: Please have a try to use the lastest version of Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer tool. If that doesn't resolve the issue, please have a try to check whether there is a CSV file reocord size  larger than 1M. If it is that case, it is not supported by azure table storage. More details please refer to updated answer.